# Equation of motion of the curvature form $F$ in Yang-Mills theory

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory, yang-mills

Following 4.2.1 in [this document](http://cds.cern.ch/record/533269/files/) (Muharrem Küskü, *The Free Maxwell Field in Curved Spacetime*, 2001), I tried to adapt the method used (in particular equations 4.21 and 4.32) to Yang-Mills theory rather than curved space-time by introducing a gauge covariant exterior derivative $d_A$, and its associated coderivative on $\mathfrak{g}$-valued $k$-forms: $(-1)^k \star^{-1} d_A \star$. These operators are such that
\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\delta_A F = 0\\
d_A F=0
\end{array}
\right.,
\end{equation*}
where $F$ is the curvature form of the gauge connection form $A$. My problem arises when I try to find a unified equation of motion for $F$ of the form $\square_A F=0$. Since the paper is using $\square_A = d_A \delta_A+\delta_A d_A$ I thought I have to use it, but I have a doubt because I can use either $\square_A = d_A \delta_A$ or $\square_A = \delta_A d_A$ since they lead to $0$ too. So, which one should I use in my derivation?

Comment: @Nihar Karve Yes of course, but as I said I have a doubt since the other two also lead to an equation of the form $\square_A F=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct equation is $(d_A\delta_A+\delta_Ad_A)F_A=0$.

The reason for using the Laplacian in the (generalised) wave equation is not as subtle as one would think: there are two conditions that the curvature form of a Yang-Mills connection must satisfy -
$$
d_AF_A=0 \qquad\text{Bianchi Identity}\tag{1}
$$
$$
d_A \star F_A = 0 \Leftrightarrow \delta_AF_A=0\qquad\text{Equation of Motion}\tag{2}
$$

So, the curvature form must be such that $F_A \in \ker(d_A\delta_A)\subseteq\bigwedge^2 T^*(M)\otimes \mathrm{ad}(P)$, *and* $F_A \in \ker(\delta_Ad_A)$. It is straightforward to show that $\ker(d_A\delta_A)\cap\ker(\delta_Ad_A)=\ker(d_A\delta_A+\delta_Ad_A)\equiv\ker\Delta$, in other words, $F_A$ is a (non-linear) generalisation of a harmonic form. The equations $d_A\delta_AF=0$ and $\delta_Ad_AF=0$ are insufficient to individually determine *whether* $A$ is a Yang-Mills connection, although they are trivially satisified for the curvature form of a Yang-Mills connection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is what I sought.